# Why does only the initially active Bootstrap tab respond correctly to window resizing, even though styling is applied consistently across tabs?

Tags: css, bootstrap-4, flexbox, tabs, plotly-dash

I am building a web app using Plotly Dash. The general layout can be seen in the attached screenshot [1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BfhF4.png). The HTML & CSS have been written so that the app fills the viewport, regardless of window size; I rely on Flexbox. Here is a simplified & collapsed version of the page's HTML:

```
<div id="_dash-app-content">
    <div id="app-container" class="full-page container-fluid"><br>
        <div>
            <ul id="tabs" class="nav nav-tabs"></ul>
            <div class="tab-content">
                <div id="tab-1" class="tab-pane active"></div>
                <div id="tab-2" class="tab-pane"></div>
                <div id="tab-3" class="tab-pane"></div>
                <div id="tab-4" class="tab-pane"></div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

And here is the associated CSS:

```
html,
body {
    height: 100vh;
}

.full-page {
    height: 100vh;
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
}

#app-container > div {
    flex-grow: 1;
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
}

.tab-content {
    flex-grow: 1;
}

.tab-pane {
    height: 100%;
}
```

When the app first loads, all tabs look great. Moreover, as long as I am on the initially active tab (let's say the first tab, `tab-1`), the tab content behaves as expected when I resize the window. This is not the case for any of the other tabs, which all resize horizontally **but not vertically** to fit the window. I assumed that it was incorrect CSS. However, if I am on any tab other than the first tab (the one that was initially active and responds correctly to window resizing), I can fix the layout by opening the web inspector tool in the browser, changing the `height` property of the `tab-pane` class from 100% to anything else, then resetting that same `height` property back to 100%. Can someone help me to understand what is happening, and hopefully how to fix it? Thanks so much!

Comment: I don't have a solution but I believe this is related to: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35297628/plotly-chart-height-resize-when-using-tabs